# How to retrieve data from a model of an App in the views of another application?

Tags: django

Hello django python developers. Indeed, I developed a django project composed of 2 applications.
MyApp and Blog

I want to retrieve the data from the MyApp App models from the database on the App Blog views without rewriting the same functions

How do I do it

Comment: In your Blog views.py add the line `from MyApp.models import YourModel` where YourModel is the model in MyApp's models.py that you want to use in the Blog app.

Answer (score 0):

You can import anything from one app to another. Just add in the top of you file proper `from ... import ...` to use it at it is.

If you want to use your class models, just do import with `from` starting from app level:

```
from MyApp.models import MyModel

my_model = MyModel.objects.first()
my_model.some_method()
```

If you have more things you want to import from a file, you can separate them with comma:

```
from MyApp.models import MyModel, some_function

my_model = MyModel.objects.first()
some_function(my_model)
```